# How to get RapidJSON schema to deal with default properties

Tags: c++, json, jsonschema, rapidjson

I have the following JSON schema, which requires both `id` and `content` but defaults the latter to an empty string.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "string" },
        "content": { "type": "string", "default": "" }
    },
    "required": [ "id", "content" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I'm trying to validate the following JSON string:

```
{
    "id": "some id"
}
```

For that, I have the following code:

```
rapidjson::Document document;
document.Parse(schemaJson.c_str());

rapidjson::SchemaDocument schemaDocument(document);
rapidjson::SchemaValidator validator(schemaDocument);

rapidjson::Document modelDoc;
modelDoc.Parse(modelJson.c_str());

modelDoc.Accept(validator); // Complains about missing property
```

The accept call fails the validation even though the property has a default value.

The [RapidJSON schema documentation](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_schema.html) claims it conforms to the [JSON Schema draft 4](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html).

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, your beef is with [JSON Schema validation spec](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html), not with RapidJSON:

> [4.3.  Default values for missing keywords](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor10)
>
> Some keywords, if absent, **MAY** be regarded by implementations as having a default value. In this case, the default value will be mentioned.

Consequence: a processor *is allowed to ignore* the missing values even if they have a `default` value provided *and still be conforming to JSON-schema validation specification*

> [5.4.3.  required](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor61)
>
> [5.4.3.2.  Conditions for successful validation](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.5.4.3.2)
> An object instance is valid against this keyword *if its property set contains all elements* in this keyword's array value.

Consequence: a validator must not ignore missing but required properties.

---

Put the two together and what gives? RapidJSON can still claim conformance to JSON Schema validation, even if it does not consider the  `default` values for `required` properties during schema validation.

You can still lodge an enhancement request in the [issues page of RapidJson project](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/issues)

Answer (score 2):

That would be an appropriate schema for what you're trying to achieve.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {},
  "id": "example",
  "properties": {
    "content": {
      "default": "1",
      "id": "/properties/content",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "id": {
      "id": "/properties/id",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "content",
    "id"
  ],
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Also, I read [here](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html?highlight=default) on Understanding JSON Schema, that many JSON Schema validators straight up ignore the `default` keyword. Maybe you'd be better off not using it.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest [pull request](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/pull/1279) merged, RapidJSON will no longer raise a `missing property` error if and when a `"default"` value (non-zero length string) is specified in the schema. See this [unit test](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/pull/1279/files#diff-3f1f6464a3739253336304ed470cbe7eR1052) as an example.

Be reminded that this update only silence the error, and it does not populate the default value to the document being validated. The user may dig out the value from the schema if such behaviour is desired.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried some online validators. They also invalidate your example.

- http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/
- http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

I will suggest you to remove `"content"` in `"required"`, if this is what you want.